# Visual Studio 2015 Debugging not stopping at breakpoints

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

I've searched for an answer to this and since VS2015 is too new, I didn't find anything.  But the problem is simple - while debugging an application, I can't get the application to break on the breakpoints.

Has anyone else encountered this?

Answer (score 2):

Are you referring to native or .NET applications? For native C++ 32-but applications, breakpoints also do not work for me (it does work in Visual Studio 2010). That is how I found this post. So the answer to your question is: Yes, others have encountered this.

I tried to set up a small sample to log for Microsoft feedback, but in the small sample application it always works.

I also cannot find anything existing on the feedback site either, I guess we need to add more details or find out when it does not work, what the magic change is.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you are still looking for an answer, but when I changed my solution platform from `x86` to `x64` it began to work.

Answer (score 1):

I updated my projects as opposed to the solution, but switched both the web project and the unit test project to "x64". I switched the web project back to "Any CPU" breakpoints are working again, just as always.

I have seen other posts which mention updating (entirely replacing) the .sln file, but perhaps that is a more blunt-instrument approach to the same underlying fix.

Thanks @Code!

Answer (score 0):

In my case nothing worked until I switched both tested and unit test projects to be built with latest (vs2017 v141) platform toolset.